# reading user define build setting in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcconfig, user-defined-fields

I have a user defined variable called `"ENVIRONMENT"`

I have a `plist` with this entry

```
Environment = ${ENVIRONMENT}
```

in my xcconfig:

```
ENVIRONMENT=Dev
```

I also set the configuration file for the project to see my `xcconfig` file.

I know this part works because it creates my `ENVIRONMENT` variable in the user defined area for my target.

So I run this line in my app delegate did finish launching:

```
NSLog(@"Env = %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"Environment"]);
```

How can I use the `xcconfig` file to set a value on main `plist` file for the project?

Comment: I have also traded putting "INFOPLIST_FILE=Staging-Info.plist" and just have different plist files instead of combining them in the xcconfig, but the xcconfig is not making the app use my custom plist. just ignoring the line com pletely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the target with the A made from pencils. Clicked duplicate and to build a copy. Set the configuration for each sub target created and it works